# data becomes unsorted after click on pagination link

Tags: php, sorting, pagination

According to many records in my database, so i when i fetch it from database and display it, the content that display is very longer. Now, i have used pagination. So it will be easy for user to see the content. I fetch data from database and display it by using table. If user click on header of table (tr), it will order by Descending/Ascending (odd click ==> Descending, event click ==> Ascending). The problem that i have faced is: when i click on header of table, so it will display content that order by descending/ascending. But when i click the pagination link (page 2 or next page), it will go to the second page, but it is not order by descending/ascending anymore. I want if i click header of table and click pagination link for the second page or another pages, it will go to the page that i click and order by descending/ascending.

**Here is my pagination code**

```
<?php

class PS_Pagination {
    var $php_self;
    var $rows_per_page = 10; //Number of records to display per page
    var $total_rows = 0; //Total number of rows returned by the query
    var $links_per_page = 5; //Number of links to display per page
    var $append = ""; //Paremeters to append to pagination links
    var $sql = "";
    var $debug = false;
    var $conn = false;
    var $page = 1;
    var $max_pages = 0;
    var $offset = 0;

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param resource $connection Mysql connection link
     * @param string $sql SQL query to paginate. Example : SELECT * FROM users
     * @param integer $rows_per_page Number of records to display per page. Defaults to 10
     * @param integer $links_per_page Number of links to display per page. Defaults to 5
     * @param string $append Parameters to be appended to pagination links 
     */

    function PS_Pagination($connection, $sql, $rows_per_page = 10, $links_per_page = 5, $append = "") {
        $this->conn = $connection;
        $this->sql = $sql;
        $this->rows_per_page = (int)$rows_per_page;
        if (intval($links_per_page ) > 0) {
            $this->links_per_page = (int)$links_per_page;
        } else {
            $this->links_per_page = 5;
        }
        $this->append = $append;
        $this->php_self = htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] );
        if (isset($_GET['page'] )) {
            $this->page = intval($_GET['page'] );
        }
    }

    /**
     * Executes the SQL query and initializes internal variables
     *
     * @access public
     * @return resource
     */
    function paginate() {
        //Check for valid mysql connection
        if (! $this->conn || ! is_resource($this->conn )) {
            if ($this->debug)
                echo "MySQL connection missing<br />";
            return false;
        }

        //Find total number of rows
        $all_rs = @mysql_query($this->sql );
        if (! $all_rs) {
            if ($this->debug)
                echo "SQL query failed. Check your query.<br /><br />Error Returned: " . mysql_error();
            return false;
        }
        $this->total_rows = mysql_num_rows($all_rs );
        @mysql_close($all_rs );

        //Return FALSE if no rows found
        if ($this->total_rows == 0) {
            if ($this->debug)
                echo "Query returned zero rows.";
            return FALSE;
        }

        //Max number of pages
        $this->max_pages = ceil($this->total_rows / $this->rows_per_page );
        if ($this->links_per_page > $this->max_pages) {
            $this->links_per_page = $this->max_pages;
        }

        //Check the page value just in case someone is trying to input an aribitrary value
        if ($this->page > $this->max_pages || $this->page <= 0) {
            $this->page = 1;
        }

        //Calculate Offset
        $this->offset = $this->rows_per_page * ($this->page - 1);

        //Fetch the required result set
        $rs = @mysql_query($this->sql . " LIMIT {$this->offset}, {$this->rows_per_page}" );
        if (! $rs) {
            if ($this->debug)
                echo "Pagination query failed. Check your query.<br /><br />Error Returned: " . mysql_error();
            return false;
        }
        return $rs;
    }

    /**
     * Display the link to the first page
     *
     * @access public
     * @param string $tag Text string to be displayed as the link. Defaults to 'First'
     * @return string
     */
    function renderFirst($tag = 'First') {
        if ($this->total_rows == 0)
            return FALSE;

        if ($this->page == 1) {
            return "$tag ";
        } else {
            return '<a style="color:#3366FF;" href="' . $this->php_self . '?page=1&' . $this->append . '">' . $tag . '</a> ';
        }
    }

    /**
     * Display the link to the last page
     *
     * @access public
     * @param string $tag Text string to be displayed as the link. Defaults to 'Last'
     * @return string
     */
    function renderLast($tag = 'Last') {
        if ($this->total_rows == 0)
            return FALSE;

        if ($this->page == $this->max_pages) {
            return $tag;
        } else {
            return ' <a style="color:#3366FF;" href="' . $this->php_self . '?page=' . $this->max_pages . '&' . $this->append . '">' . $tag . '</a>';
        }
    }

    /**
     * Display the next link
     *
     * @access public
     * @param string $tag Text string to be displayed as the link. Defaults to '>>'
     * @return string
     */
    function renderNext($tag = '&gt;&gt;') {
        if ($this->total_rows == 0)
            return FALSE;

        if ($this->page < $this->max_pages) {
            return '<a style="color:#3366FF;" href="' . $this->php_self . '?page=' . ($this->page + 1) . '&' . $this->append . '">' . $tag . '</a>';
        } else {
            return $tag;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Display the previous link
     *
     * @access public
     * @param string $tag Text string to be displayed as the link. Defaults to '<<'
     * @return string
     */
    function renderPrev($tag = '&lt;&lt;') {
        if ($this->total_rows == 0)
            return FALSE;

        if ($this->page > 1) {
            return ' <a style="color:#3366FF;" href="' . $this->php_self . '?page=' . ($this->page - 1) . '&' . $this->append . '">' . $tag . '</a>';
        } else {
            return " $tag";
        }
    }

    /**
     * Display the page links
     *
     * @access public
     * @return string
     */
    function renderNav($prefix = '<span class="page_link">', $suffix = '</span>') {
        if ($this->total_rows == 0)
            return FALSE;

        $batch = ceil($this->page / $this->links_per_page );
        $end = $batch * $this->links_per_page;
        if ($end == $this->page) {
            //$end = $end + $this->links_per_page - 1;
        //$end = $end + ceil($this->links_per_page/2);
        }
        if ($end > $this->max_pages) {
            $end = $this->max_pages;
        }
        $start = $end - $this->links_per_page + 1;
        $links = '';

        for($i = $start; $i <= $end; $i ++) {
            if ($i == $this->page) {
                $links .= $prefix . " $i " . $suffix;
            } else {
                $links .= ' ' . $prefix . '<a style="color:#3366FF;" href="' . $this->php_self . '?page=' . $i . '&' . $this->append . '">' . $i . '</a>' . $suffix . ' ';
            }
        }

        return $links;
    }

    /**
     * Display full pagination navigation
     *
     * @access public
     * @return string
     */
    function renderFullNav() {
        return $this->renderFirst() . '&nbsp;' . $this->renderPrev() . '&nbsp;' . $this->renderNav() . '&nbsp;' . $this->renderNext() . '&nbsp;' . $this->renderLast();
    }

    /**
     * Set debug mode
     *
     * @access public
     * @param bool $debug Set to TRUE to enable debug messages
     * @return void
     */
    function setDebug($debug) {
        $this->debug = $debug;
    }
}
?>
```

**My page**

```
<?php
session_start();
include('pagination/ps_pagination.php');
$sql = "SELECT * FROM contact_us";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
echo "<table border='1' width='90%' align='center' style='border-collapse:collapse; table-layout: fixed;'>";
    echo "<tr>";
        echo "<th width='40%'><a style='text-decoration:none; href='index.php?no'>No</a></th>";
        echo "<th width='60%'><a style='text-decoration:none; href='index.php?name'>Name</a></th>";
    echo "</tr>";
    if(mysql_num_rows($result) <= 0){
        echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td colspan='2'>No user!</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    else{
        if(isset($_GET['no'])){
            $count = 1;
            $_SESSION['t_no'] = $_SESSION['t_no'] + $count;
            if($_SESSION['t_no'] % 2 == 0){
                $sql.=" ORDER BY No DESC";
            }
            else{
                $sql.=" ORDER BY No ASC";
            }
        }
        elseif(isset($_GET['name'])){
            $count = 1;
            $_SESSION['t_name'] = $_SESSION['t_name'] + $count;
            if($_SESSION['t_name'] % 2 == 0){
                $sql.=" ORDER BY User_Name DESC";
            }
            else{
                $sql.=" ORDER BY User_Name ASC";
            }
        }

        $final = $sql;

        //Create a PS_Pagination object
        $pager = new PS_Pagination($conn, $final, 40, 10); //only 10 records

        //The paginate() function returns a mysql result set for the current page
        $rs = $pager->paginate();
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs)){
            echo "<tr style='cursor:pointer;'>";
                echo "<td style='word-wrap:break-word;'>".$row['No']."</td>";
                echo "<td style='word-wrap:break-word;'>".$row['User_Name']."</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
        }
    }
echo "</table>";
echo "<br/>";
echo '<div style="text-align:center">'.$pager->renderFullNav().'</div>';
?>
```

Can you help me to solve this problem? I got stuck with it several days :(

Thank in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php
session_start();
include('pagination/ps_pagination.php');
$sql = "SELECT * FROM contact_us";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$append = '';
echo "<table border='1' width='90%' align='center' style='border-collapse:collapse; table-layout: fixed;'>";
    echo "<tr>";
        echo "<th width='40%'><a style='text-decoration:none; href='index.php?no'>No</a></th>";
        echo "<th width='60%'><a style='text-decoration:none; href='index.php?name'>Name</a></th>";
    echo "</tr>";
    if(mysql_num_rows($result) <= 0){
        echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td colspan='2'>No user!</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    else{

        if(isset($_GET['no'])){
            $count = 1;
            $_SESSION['t_no'] = $_SESSION['t_no'] + $count;
            $append = "no=" . $_SESSION['t_no'];
            if($_SESSION['t_no'] % 2 == 0){
                $sql.=" ORDER BY No DESC";
            }
            else{
                $sql.=" ORDER BY No ASC";
            }
        }
        elseif(isset($_GET['name'])){
            $count = 1;
            $_SESSION['t_name'] = $_SESSION['t_name'] + $count;
            $append = "name=" . $_SESSION['t_name'];
            if($_SESSION['t_name'] % 2 == 0){
                $sql.=" ORDER BY User_Name DESC";
            }
            else{
                $sql.=" ORDER BY User_Name ASC";
            }
        }

        $final = $sql;

        //Create a PS_Pagination object
        $pager = new PS_Pagination($conn, $final, 40, 10, $append); //only 10 records

        //The paginate() function returns a mysql result set for the current page
        $rs = $pager->paginate();
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs)){
            echo "<tr style='cursor:pointer;'>";
                echo "<td style='word-wrap:break-word;'>".$row['No']."</td>";
                echo "<td style='word-wrap:break-word;'>".$row['User_Name']."</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
        }
    }
echo "</table>";
echo "<br/>";
echo '<div style="text-align:center">'.$pager->renderFullNav().'</div>';
?>
```

Comment: i have changed it, nothing change. I don't know where $append is used in your code.

Comment: Its used as the last parameter to PS_Pagination constructor

Comment: sorry it was my mistake. i already place it at the last parameter, but it still not work :(

Comment: Check in your navigation link if there the GET parameters name or no are set.

Comment: i don't know how to know the GET parameters name or no are set. would you mind telling me about this?

Comment: check in the url if you are seeing anything like ?name=1 or something?

Comment: check the query by echo $final;